# Word Macro to determine whether document contains highlighting

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to write a macro that displays a popup when a user clicks save (I have it as Sub FileSave() ) if the document contains any highlighting. So far, everything works great with the message box. Unfortunately I can't figure out which conditions to use for the if statement to check whether the document contains highlighting or not.

Can anyone help me with a few lines of VBA for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to search for highlighted text within document content in this way:

```
Sub SearchAnyHighlight()

Dim hiliRng As Range
Set hiliRng = ActiveDocument.Content

With hiliRng.Find
    .Highlight = True
    .Execute
End With

If hiliRng.Find.Found Then
    'to inform that something was found
    MsgBox "You can't close Active Document"
    'to remove all highlighted area <-- added after edition
    With hiliRng.Find
        .Replacement.Highlight = False
        .Execute "", Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
            ReplaceWith:="", Format:=True
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Quick question--so if I want to then delete all highlights, my code using .Forward = True deletes all the OTHER highlights except that first one. I assume it's because the first highlight was selected in the Find. How can I ensure that it goes back and deletes that one, too?

Comment: @user2259920, see extended code in the answer... It remove all highlights, including first one. If you are still happy please remember to mark question as solved...